# why is not possible to have static members in struct?

Tags: c, struct, static

First, from this:

```
static struct foo1 { //private struct, just for this file
    int a;
};

int main (void) {
    struct foo1 a = {10};
    return 0;
}
```

*question number 1*

I will get warning:

```
warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
```

What does it mean? Why is `static` "useless storage class specifier"? In other context (static local var in function, or global static, which I wanted to apply for the struct `foo1`, it would work).

*question number 2*

```
#include <stdbool.h>
static struct s_t{ //private struct (for this file only) 
    static bool is_there = false; // defaul (pre-defined) value for all instances
    int value;
};

int main (void) {}
```

Why is not possible to have static, predefined value for all vars of type `struct s_t` in c? I just wanted to simulate the same functionality as is in function `static local var` -> **preserve** value across multiple calls, in that sense, I wanted have one member (`bool is_there` in this case) that **preserve** value across each var of type `struct foo1` (instance of it). So why it is not possible?

*question number 3*

Also, can someone explain the error (in more general sense) from it:

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘static’
```

EDIT:
from comments, I do not really understand the concept of storage class, I know only from asm, there is `data/text/bss segments`, so does it mean `static var` has address in `read-only` part of memory? Or what is the concept of `storage class` in c related to asm?

Comment: What would be the expected result of having a `static` member in a struct when you allocate memory for that instance via `malloc`? What would be the effect of having different storage classes for different members? Or between members and the struct itself? A struct is only a blueprint for some data object. It does not specify where this will end up. You seem to mix up static objects in C and static classes in C++

Comment: @Gerhardh i know it is just "blueprint", but how can I achieve then to have one member `pre-defined`? I just do not want to initilize for each var of that type the same value, when it could have all of them. I thought that is what `static` is for

Comment: @Gerhardh I am not mixing `C++` with pure `C`, by *instance*, I meant a variable of type `struct  s_t` (not instance of class) I just shorthanded it to `instance`, but this question is strictly for `C` lang.

Comment: Static members do not exist in C. Same for predefined values.

Comment: A blueprint defines the layout. It does not bring all the furniture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Because `static struct foo1 { ...` is just a struct definition, not a variable. You should add `static` when you declare the instance of the struct. I prefer this style:

   ```
   typedef struct  { 
       int a;
   }foo_t;

   static foo_t a = {10};
   ```
2. Because C simply doesn't have static member variables like C++ does. In C, it's pretty useless to add storage- or type specifiers to a single struct member. Put it on the allocated variables instead.
3. TL;DR it's just not making any sense of your syntax since you can't have `static` there. Unless you are terribly interested about language grammar, there's nothing else to it.

   `static` is a *storage-class specifier* and `const` etc are *type qualifiers* and `int` etc is a *type specifier*. The term *specifier-qualifier list* comes from formal C grammar of structs, which isn't terribly interesting to read unless you are making a compiler. When declaring a struct member you have two options (C17 6.7.2.1):

   ```
   specifier-qualifier-list:
      type-specifier specifier-qualifier-list(opt)
      type-qualifier specifier-qualifier-list(opt)
   ```

   `static` doesn't fit the bill of either, being a storage-class specifier, so the compiler is saying "what! this is not a specifier-qualifier list where I expected to find one, where is it?"

   (And yeah it's recursive, so you can have multiple of type-specifier or type-qualifier such as `const long const const int value;`. Because C stands for Crazy.)

Comment: The same as in comments for @Gerhardh. If C does not have static member in struct, How I can then achieve to have one member with value for all other initiliaze variables with that type? I only wanted to achive, that all variables of type `struct s_t` will have already defined member `bool is_there` to `false`. That is what I think the `static` keyword is for. Also Can you please explain your mentioned `storage classes` in relation to asm segments? (As I am asking in my edit)

Comment: @autistic456 No, `static` means that a variable has "internal linkage" (can't be accessed from other files) and static storage duration (meaning it will end up allocated in .data or .bss). If you want read-only, you should use `const`. Which _is_ allowed to place before a struct member, though I wouldn't really recommend that from a program design point-of-view.

Comment: @autistic456 If you come from assembler to C you might find this helpful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/237759/6102. It was written with microcontrollers in mind, but it's pretty much universal, at least for "ELF-like" binaries.

Answer (score 3):

because struct is like a type or an object, when you declare a static member in C, it would be like:

```c
static int a = 0;
```

In this case "int" is like the struct type you declared, so if you want to create a struct static member just do like this:

```c
static s_t a;
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> static struct foo1 { //private struct, just for this file
>         int a;
>     };
> ```

The `static` declaration specifier only applies to object or function declarations, not type definitions.  All you're doing in that statement is creating the `struct foo1` type.  Had you written something like

```
static struct foo1 {
  int a;
} foo;
```

Then the *object* `foo` would be declared `static`.

If you declare the type within the `.c` file, it will only be visible within that `.c` file.  The only way to make the type visible to multiple `.c` files is to declare it in a header and `#include` that header in each file that needs it.

> Why is not possible to have static, predefined value for all vars of type `struct s_t` in c?

Because C `struct` types are simply not that sophisticated - they're just a way to define a data item with multiple attributes.  The language doesn't provide any way to have members that are common across all instances of the type.

Remember that C is a product of the early 1970s and was originally developed to implement the Unix operating system - it was designed to be small, portable, and fast.  A lot's been added to it over the last 40-some-odd years, but nothing that really changes the core philosophy of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its quite evident that you will get the warning. The reason is simple! **You are trying to assign a Storage Class to the `struct` definition**. 
However, storage classes are applicable to variable declarations. Therefore, you are getting the prompt.
If you still wish to employ the `static` storage class, then you can do so with any variable, preferably, any instance of the structure.